# How to parse a single escape character between escape characters using ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I have a string like `RANDOM = "SOMEGIBBERISH ("DOG CAT-DOG","DOG CAT-DOG")"`. For quoted string literals I use:

```
StringLiteralSQ : UnterminatedStringLiteralSQ '\'' ;
UnterminatedStringLiteralSQ : '\'' (~['\r\n] | '\\' (. | EOF))* ;   
StringLiteralDQ : UnterminatedStringLiteralDQ '"' ;
UnterminatedStringLiteralDQ : '"' (~[\r\n] | '\\' (. | EOF))* ;
```

This parses the above mentioned String. I need to identify them words as comma separated tokens like this **DOG CAT-DOG**. for this I use something like

```
options : name EQUALS value
  | OPTIONS L_PAREN (name EQUALS value) (COMMA (name EQUALS value)* R_PAREN
  ;
```

However, when I make the string of this format `RANDOM = "SOMEGIBBERISH ("DOG CAT-DOG"DOG CAT-DOG")"`, it fails with an out-of-memory error.

I wanted to parse the strings that I have been parsing before and also parse this kind of string `("DOG CAT-DOG"DOG CAT-DOG")` and consider it a single token maybe. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, so I'm not sure I understand what you are after. You ask for handling escaped characters, but then you don't show any input which uses escapes.

However, I think you are making things way too complicated. Look in other grammars to see how they define string tokens, including escape handling. Here's a typical example:

```
fragment SINGLE_QUOTE: '\'';
fragment DOUBLE_QUOTE: '"';

DOUBLE_QUOTED_TEXT: (
        DOUBLE_QUOTE ('\\'? .)*? DOUBLE_QUOTE
    )+
;

SINGLE_QUOTED_TEXT: (
        SINGLE_QUOTE ('\\'? .)*? SINGLE_QUOTE
    )+
;
```